# How to match Named Entities based on each sentence not through a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file and I implement the Polyglot NER to extract the entities from this text file. Then I have to segment each sentence and matched the extracted entities on each sentence. When matched it should give me the output.

```py
from polyglot.text import Text
file = open('input_raw.txt', 'r')
input_file = file.read()
file = Text(input_file, hint_language_code='fa')

def return_match(entities_list, sentence):       ## Check if Chunks
    for term in entities_list:                  ## are in any of the entities
        ## Check each list in each Chunk object 
        ## and see if there's any matches.
        for entity in sentence.entities:
            if entity == term:
                return entity
    return None

def return_list_of_entities(file):
    list_entity = []
    for sentence in file.sentences:
        for entity in sentence.entities:
            list_entity.append(entity)
    return list_entity

list_entity = return_list_of_entities(file)
#sentence_number = 4 # Which sentence to check
for sentence in range(len(file.sentences)):
    sentencess = file.sentences[sentence]


match = return_match(list_entity, sentencess)

if match is not None:
    print("Entity Term " + str(match) +  
          " is in the sentence. '" + str(sentencess)+ "'")
else:
    print("Sentence '" + str(sentencess) + 
          "' doesn't contain any of the terms" + str(list_entity))
```

input_file:

```
Bill Gates is the founder of Microsoft.
Trump is the president of the USA.
Bill Gates was a student in Harvard.
```

When we implement the NER the entities look like:

list_etity:

```
Bill Gates, Microsoft, Trump, USA, Bill Gate, Harvard
```

When we match the entities with the first sentence, it gives:

Current output:

```
(Bill Gates, Bill Gates, Microsoft)
```

Expected output:

```
(Bill Gates, Microsoft) # this is from the first sentence and should contine
(Trump, USA) 
(Bill Gates, Harvard)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from polyglot.text import Text
import json
file = open('input_raw.txt', 'r')
input_file = file.read()
file = Text(input_file, hint_language_code='fa')

result = set()
entities_with_tag = []
def return_match(entities_list, sentence):  # Check if Chunks
    for i in range(len(sentence.entities)):
        for j in range(len(entities_list)):
            if entities_list[j] == sentence.entities[i]:
                # result.append(sentence.entities[i])
                result.add(str(sentence.entities[i]))
                entities_with_tag.append(sentence.entities[i])

def return_list_of_entities(file):
    list_entity = []
    for sentence in file.sentences:
        for entity in sentence.entities:
            list_entity.append(entity)
    return list_entity

list_entity = return_list_of_entities(file)

def return_sentence_number():
    for i in range(len(file.sentences)):
        sentence_no = file.sentences[i]
        return sentence_no

sent_no = return_sentence_number()
return_match(list_entity, sent_no)
print("Entity Term " + str(result) + " is in the sentence. '" + str(sent_no) + "'")
```